# R - chr Date conversion

Tags: r, date, finance

I can't convert my chr Dates to a Date format. Please help.

[image: This is]

This is my Data frame. As you can see the dates are in `rv_data_USDC_DAILY$Date`

```
as.Date.character(rv_data_USDC_DAILY$Date, "%b-%d-%y")

as.Date(rv_data_USDC_DAILY$Date, format = "%b-%d-%y") 

strptime(rv_data_USDC_DAILY$Date, "%b-%d-%y")
```

This is what I tried.

[image]

This is my output. Lot of NAs :/

Following your requests:

```
> dput(rv_data_USDC_DAILY[1:5, "Date", drop = FALSE])
structure(list(Date = c("Jun-29-2022", "Jun-28-2022", "Jun-27-2022", 
"Jun-26-2022", "Jun-25-2022")), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=French_France.utf8;LC_CTYPE=French_France.utf8;LC_MONETARY=French_France.utf8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=French_France.utf8"

[1] "Jun-29-2022" "Jun-28-2022" "Jun-27-2022" "Jun-26-2022" "Jun-25-2022" "Jun-24-2022" "Jun-23-2022" "Jun-22-2022" "Jun-21-2022" "Jun-20-2022"
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you nees a capital Y. Try `as.Date(rv_data_USDC_DAILY$Date, format = "%b-%d-%Y")`

Comment: My code gives me an array of NAs. I also tried with a capital Y, not working.

Comment: What gives `Sys.getlocale()`?

Comment: `lubridate::mdy(rv_data_USDC_DAILY$Date)`. If you need more help, please share your locale info as jay.sf asks and also please share some sample data as text, not as pictures. `dput(rv_data_USDC_DAILY[1:5, "Date", drop = FALSE])` would be perfect as it will be copy/pasteable and include the class and structure info.

Comment: "LC_COLLATE=French_France.utf8;LC_CTYPE=French_France.utf8;LC_MONETARY=French_France.utf8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=French_France.utf8"

Comment: I edited the post with your requests. Ty guys

Comment: Try `withr::with_locale(new = c("LC_TIME" = "en_US.UTF-8"), as.Date("Jun-28-2022", format = "%b-%d-%Y"))`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Gregor Thomas for his solution.

```
lubridate::mdy(rv_data_USDC_DAILY$Date).
```

Worked perfectly.